# modulo vs bitwise op

Tags: scheme, bit-manipulation, modulo

Which of the following methods is more efficient ( in Scheme, but I guess it doesn't matter)?
(The objective is to get the least significant bit)

`(define (lsb n) (- n (bitwise-and n (- n 1))))`

`(define (lsb n) (remainder n 2))`

(For those who aren't familiar with Scheme.

```
int lsb (int n)
{
    return n % 2;
}
```

vs

```
int lsb (int n)
{
    return n - (n & (n - 1));
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Before you care about performance, you need to make them do the same things. Just for example, given 1024 as the parameter, your first returns 1024 and your second returns 0.

Comment: `n % 2` is almost equivalent to `n & 1` (but not quite, `remainder` has the sign of the dividend), not to `n & -n` (which is what `n - (n & (n - 1))` is doing in a roundabout way). You've managed to make "least significant bit" ambiguous - do you mean the bit with a weight of one, or the lowest set bit?

Comment: by LSB, I meant the rightmost bit

Comment: So `n & 1`, right? Or `modulo n 2`. I'd probably go for `n & 1` just to be safe - firstly, no compiler could even mess that up, and secondly, you're working with bits so work with bits, not remainders.

Comment: Now you've lost me harold. How come `n & 1` is the same thing as `n % 2` ?

Comment: @user1508893 it isn't, really. That's why I used `modulo` (uses sign of divisor) rather than `remainder` (sign of dividend). As for why they're related at all, it follows from how a binary number works - a number is even if and only if the LSB is set (1 is the only odd power of two, so without setting the ones bit it's impossible to create an odd number).

Comment: @harold Well, I know that the LSB relates to wether a number is odd or even. Which is why, I use lsb() function mentioned above to implement my isEven() function. No the original question was, which one is more efficient? The bitwise route or the remainder/modulo route?

Comment: @user1508893 the bitwise way should never be slower and could potentially be faster (if the compiler is silly)

Comment: @harold A number is even iff the LSB is **set**? Seriously? Okay, for negative numbers under a ones'-complement system, sure. But otherwise, no. (Seriously, though, even a corrected version of that assertion, that a number is odd iff the LSB is set, only holds for a two's-complement system, or for positive numbers.)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I restructured that sentence and didn't proofread it.. oh well.

Answer (score 0):

If DIV have become more efficient in new CPUs it certainly wouldn't be faster than a bitwise operation so bitwise-and would probably, on most architectures, knock the socks out of remainder (that implies a div instruction)

If all you care about is the lsb why not write it like this:

```
(define (lsb n)
   (bitwise-and 1 n))
```

Answer (score 0):

You write incorrect question. You're trying to compare performance of different functions. For example, for n == 2, your 1st function returns zero, when 2nd returns 2.

so, if you want optimize both functions, then they are:

1st:

```
return n & 1;
```

2nd:

```
return n & -n;
```